# Problem saving model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model

I'm building a simple blog with comments. There is a Post model and a Comment model. Every interaction between the two works fine except for creating new comments. I'm having an issue in Rails when trying to post a new comment:

```
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

Here are the request parameters (from the stack trace):

```
{"commit"=>"Post My Comment",
 "post_id"=>"1",
 "authenticity_token"=>"5a7b3ad3dda771d4ef5eb5850018649a8be2af11",
 "comment"=>{"name"=>"bj",
 "website"=>"asdf.com",
 "comment"=>"asdf",
 "email"=>"asdf@asdf.com"}}
```

And the full stack trace:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.1.0/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:296:in `notify'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.1.0/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:296:in `callback'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.1.0/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:263:in `valid?'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.1.0/lib/active_record/validations.rb:900:in `save_without_dirty'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.1.0/lib/active_record/dirty.rb:75:in `save_without_transactions'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.1.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:106:in `save'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:66:in `transaction'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.1.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:79:in `transaction'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.1.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:98:in `transaction'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.1.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:106:in `save'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.1.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:118:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.1.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:106:in `save'
app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:39:in `create'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.1.0/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1162:in `send'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.1.0/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1162:in `perform_action_without_filters'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.1.0/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:580:in `call_filters'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.1.0/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:573:in `perform_action_without_benchmark'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.1.0/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_without_rescue'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.1.0/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_without_rescue'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.1.0/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:201:in `perform_action_without_caching'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.1.0/lib/action_controller/caching/sql_cache.rb:13:in `perform_action'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:33:in `cache'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.1.0/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:8:in `cache'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.1.0/lib/action_controller/caching/sql_cache.rb:12:in `perform_action'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.1.0/lib/action_controller/base.rb:529:in `send'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.1.0/lib/action_controller/base.rb:529:in `process_without_filters'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.1.0/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:569:in `process_without_session_management_support'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.1.0/lib/action_controller/session_management.rb:130:in `process'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.1.0/lib/action_controller/base.rb:389:in `process'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/rails.rb:76:in `process'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/rails.rb:74:in `synchronize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/rails.rb:74:in `process'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:159:in `process_client'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:158:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:158:in `process_client'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `initialize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `new'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `initialize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `new'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:282:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:281:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:281:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:128:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/command.rb:212:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:281
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:502:in `load'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:502:in `load'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:354:in `new_constants_in'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:502:in `load'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.1.0/lib/commands/servers/mongrel.rb:64
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:509:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:354:in `new_constants_in'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:509:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.1.0/lib/commands/server.rb:39
```

I've narrowed the error down to the save method I'm calling on the Comment Model:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.1.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:106:in `save'
app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:39:in `create'
```

The form in my partial that is generating the error (when I post) is as follows (form_row is a simple helper method I created to create, well, a form row):

```
<% form_for [post, new_comment] do |f| %>
<%= form_row('Name', f.text_field(:name, :size => 30), 'comment_name') %>
<%= form_row('Email', f.text_field(:email, :size => 30) + content_tag(:span, "*", :class => "required"), 'comment_email') %>
<%= form_row('Website', f.text_field(:website, :size => 30) + content_tag(:span, "*", :class => "required"), 'comment_website') %>
<%= form_row('Comment', f.text_area(:comment, { :rows => 10, :cols => 40 }), 'comment_comment') %>
<%= form_row('', '<span class="sm-text"><span class="required">*</span> Denotes fields that will not be displayed on your comment</span>') %>
<%= form_row('', submit_tag("Post My Comment")) %>
<% end -%>
```

I suspect the issue is how I'm using `form_for`, but I've tried every possible combination and incantation, and still can't figure this one out. My Post and Comment Models are as follows:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  has_many :tags, :through => :posts_tags
  belongs_to :user

  validates_presence_of :user_id, :title, :body
  validates_numericality_of :user_id
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :posts

  validates_presence_of :post_id, :name, :email, :comment
  validates_numericality_of :post_id
end
```

And finally, the controller code performing the save:

```
def create
  begin
    @comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])
    @comment.name = 'Anonymous' if @comment.name.nil?
    if @comment.save # the error occurs here
      ...
```

I'm truly stumped. Thanks in advance for the assistance.

Comment: Please attach the full error output (message + stack trace)

Comment: I just added the stack trace and request parameters for you.

Comment: Did you define a "notify" method (def notify()) anywhere in your model(s)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have probably defined a `notify` attribute (column) in your model table, clashing with the framework method `notify(...)`.  Use a different column name, such as `notify_me`.

Comment: I do have a notify boolean column on the comment table, renaming should fix this?

Comment: That solved my issue, thank you so much. I renamed the notify column to do_notify and I am no longer getting an error. The comment is not being saved, but I can debug that further, was stumped on this. Thanks!